# Using the verb graduate with the major or field of study (completing study of a field)

Tags: grammar

I was googling to see how the verb graduate is used. `graduate college` or `graduate from college`. and I got my answer to this in an article about this:

> Did you catch that ugly grammatical blunder? The problem is with the verb: graduated. In this context, it should always take the preposition from.
>
> Graduated from. You don't graduate college. College graduates you. You graduate from college.

However I couldn't find anything about completing study of some field and not college or highs school. Is it used the same? like this:

I have graduated from Computer Engineering.

or is there another verb to describe completing a field of study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually expressed as:

- I graduated with a degree in (Some Discipline).

or:

- I graduated from (Some University) with a degree in (Some Discipline).

If it's an advanced degree:

- I have a (Degree) from (Some University) in (Some Discipline).

or:

- I have a (Degree) in (Some Discipline) from (Some University)